# Add text (from another html page) to a current html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>The select Element</h2>
<p>The select element defines a drop-down list:</p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="Volvo/text.html">Volvo</option>
    <option value="Saab/text.html">Saab</option>
    <option value="Fiat/text.html">Fiat</option>
    <option value="Audi/text.html">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<table>

</table>


</body>
</html>
```

What I would like to do is based on my selection, get the html text of say Audi/text.html and insert it between the table tags. So it would look like...

```html
<table>

<tr>
  <td> Some Audi text </td>
  <td> Some more text</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Obviously, when the selection is changed, the content would change. If someone knows a better way to do this w/o javascript, that would be even better.

Thank you!

Comment: there are 20 different ways of doing this, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes, I am just able to diplay the value of the selection, but not the content. I am not proficient in javascript, and am not sure how to get the html content, and insert it into my page.  I also tried javascript:location.href but it just opens the page a separate window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather suggest you to use jQuery with some ajax calls

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // On Page Load this is going to be executed
  $.ajax({
    url: "Volbo/text.html" ,
  }).always(function(data) {
    $("#myTable").html(data);
  });
  // on Select change this is going to be executed
  $("#drop").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.value,
    }).always(function(data) {
      $("#myTable").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drop" name="cars">
        <option value="Volvo/text.html">Volvo</option>
        <option value="Saab/text.html">Saab</option>
        <option value="Fiat/text.html">Fiat</option>
        <option value="Audi/text.html">Audi</option>
      </select>

    <table id="myTable">
    
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks a million Hamouda. It works fine. I don't understand exactly how this works, but I will try and build on this.

Comment: @user1311034 anytime you are welcome , please mark my answer as solved

Comment: A followup question, when the page loads, Volvo is displayed in the select menu list, but it does not populate with the desired content. Only if I select something else and then go back to Volvo does it load. How can I load it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

It will not be possible to do this without a bit of JS because it requires listening for an event and changing the text accordingly. From my understanding of the question you want the selection to replace the first td element within the table every time a new option is selected. With that in mind something like this should work.

I'll begin by adding an id to your select box and first td element so we can easily target them both. Then I will add an event listener so every time the selection changes the text will change accordingly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>The select Element</h2>
        <p>The select element defines a drop-down list:</p>
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <select id="cars" name="cars">
                <option value="Volvo/text.html">Volvo</option>
                <option value="Saab/text.html">Saab</option>
                <option value="Fiat/text.html">Fiat</option>
                <option value="Audi/text.html">Audi</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="switcheroo"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
        (function() {
            var tdEl = document.getElementById('switcheroo'),
            select = document.getElementById('cars');
            select.addEventListener('change', function() {
                tdEl.innerHTML = this.value;
            });
        })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if this meets your requirements.. now that I'm rereading your question it might not quite be exactly what you're looking for but hopefully it's pretty close and will see you towards the proper solution

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. However, when I run the code, it just inserts the value, for example 'Volvo/text.html', not the content on this page (which is the rows described above.) The <tr><td> content </td></tr> is part of the content I want inserted.

Comment: O I see. Hamouda down below is on the money.. The way the solution works is it makes an asynchronous server request for the relevant document and then retrieves it and inserts it in the webpage. Mark his solution as solved!